# Code doesn't see when table is empty and when it has an element in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am currently working on coding a javascript chess game. I am using tables as my board and images as my pieces. Each "square" on the table has a class that specifies its location on the board. Each column has a number 1-8 and each row has a number 0-70, I gave each square its class by combining the row and column. For example, d6 on a chess board has a class in the HTML as "24". I made my code this way hoping to use it to constrict each of the peaces movements on the board. Everything was working until I tried to tell the computer that if a square has something inside it, the pawn can go diagonally. But my computer won't see if a square has a piece inside it. 
This is the part of the code I was talking about:

```
    $("td").click(function() {
    var bClass = $(this).attr('class');
    bClass = parseInt(bClass);
    var oneF = '.' + (bClass + 10).toString();
    var diagonalTake = '.' + (bClass + 11).toString();
    var $box = $(this);
    if ($box.length === 1) {
        var id = event.target.id;
        if (id === "0" && turn % 2 == 1) {
            var x = 0;
                             alert("You have clicked on a white pawn");
            //second box clicked
            $(oneF).click(function() {

                var $box2 = $(this);
                ($box).empty();
                $(oneF).empty();
                $(oneF).prepend('<img id="0" class="wp" src="http://www.charbase.com/images/glyph/9817">');
             while (x <1){
                turn++;
                x++;
             }
            });

             if (($(diagonalTake).children).length > 0){}
           else{ $(diagonalTake).click(function() {

                 var $box2 = $(this);
                 ($box).empty();
                 $(diagonalTake).empty();
                 $(diagonalTake).prepend('<img id="0" class="wp" src="http://www.charbase.com/images/glyph/9817">');

                 turn++;
           });
               }
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I would recommend separating your row and column values.  it is certainly possible to do this using an int, but this schema will get very complicated.  I'd use data-row and data-col attributes on the cells and use those.  As is, bClass+11 will not always be diagonal forward-right as you intend.

Comment: Also, use parseInt(bClass, 10) just in case the parseInt is being funny.